# Percentage of trans-stilbene traces in cis-stilbene H NMR

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

This is H NMR spectrum of cis-stilbene. There are some traces of trans stilbene. I have to determine how many trans-stilbene is present, the exact percentage and I have problem with that.

I guess that it has to do with integration of peaks but I'm still not sure is trans-cis isomer ratio 1:10 or am I wrong?

[image: cis stilbene H NMR]

Comment: Step 1: identify which peaks correspond to cis and which to trans.

Comment: Small peaks at 7,35 ppm and 7,51 ppm correspond to trans isomer and peaks at 7,27-7,15 ppm and 6,59 ppm correspond to cis isomer.

Comment: For accurate integration you also need to set the recycle delay to a longer value than usual (e.g. ~20 s), although I appreciate this may not be possible in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to focus on the $\ce{^1H}$ of the double bond. 
They are singlets because both molecules are completely symmetrical. 
As per the tables, the chemical shift of the *cis* isomer is $5.25+1.38-0.07=6.56$ ppm. 
On the other hand, the chemical shift of the *trans* isomer is
$5.25+1.38+0.36=6.99$ ppm.

These theoretical values correspond to the peaks of 6.60 and 7.11 ppm. 
Since their integrals are of 1 and 1.1571 respectively, the proportion of *trans* is of:

$\frac{0.1571}{0.1571+1}100=14\%$

Comment: Instead of using tables, a better way is to simply [look up](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi) the data: *cis*-stilbene comes in at 6.572 and *trans*-stilbene at 7.15.

Comment: @orthocresol Very correct, but the question looks like the OP is learning to interpret NMR, so I thought it was better to do it with the tables

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I'm still learning to interpret NMR. :)